# How can I use vlookup function for multiple table array that has different length?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to import the minimum value form Column C to column B for each item, but the problem is that the table array is different for every item.

Since I can't upload any image, I will just type the example here.

```
    A          B     C   
1  Item A          $10
2                  $8
3                  $9 
4  Item B          $4
5                  $5
6  Item C          $2
7  Item D          $23
```

What would be the best way to solve this problem? I have about 10000 rows !! Please help me!!

Comment: Post  a link to the image, and someone will insert it into the question for you.

Comment: You have blanks between items in column A rather than repeating the Item's name?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It has a Group By command which includes a "Min" operation. It's documented here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-rows-in-a-table-Power-Query-e1b9e916-6fcc-40bf-a6e8-ef928240adf1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

I had a go at this particular challenge and got it working. You can download and use my demo file from my OneDrive:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: Power Query demo - finding minimum value in a range of rows.

As described on the ReadMe sheet, I didn't have to write any functions - it was built by clicking around the UI.